# Closed subgroup (Cartan) theorem without transversality nor Lipschitz condition within Banach algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential-equations, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Yesterday, I came across the following preliminary theorem.

**Theorem** Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Banach algebra (with unit $e$) and $G$ be a closed subgroup 
of $\mathcal{B}^{-1}$ (the group of multiplicative inverses). Let $L(G)$ be the tangent space of $G$ and $m:\ I\to L(G)$ be a continuous function ($I\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval containing $0_\mathbb{R}$), then 
 
i) The following system 
$$
y'(t)=m(t)y(t)\ ;\ y(0)=e
$$ 
admits a unique solution, say $s(t)$.
ii) The trajectory of $s$ is entirely in $G$ (in other words $t\mapsto s(t)$ is a path drawn 
on $G$).

*My questions* are the following: 
Q1) Is it known? (I expect so, at least of the specialists)

Q2) If yes, is there a sound reference? (not general, but about this – very simple – precise property).